# Add object that called method to a list

Tags: c#, list, queue

I am trying to make a simple achievement class in C# + XNA, and I want to implement a queue so that when you get multiple achievements quickly after eachother, the latter will be added to a queue list.

Here is the method that is being called to get a certain achievement:

```
//This is the list that I want to add the achievements to be queued to
static List<Achievement> queueList;

public void GetAchievement()
{
        //If the player hasn't got the achievement yet and another achievement is NOT being drawn, get the achievement
        if (!got && !drawing)
            get = true;
        //If the player hasn't got the achievement yet and another achievement IS being drawn, add the achievement to the queue list
        else if (!got && drawing)
            queueList.Add(); //What do I do here?
 }
```

So this would be called like: exampleAchievement.GetAchievement(); with exampleAchievement being an object of the Achievement class.

I just can't figure out how to know which object is calling GetAchievement(), so I don't know what to add to queueList.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

~Luca

EDIT:
I used:

```
queueList.Add(this);
```

but I was just being dumb and didn't test it correctly, so it looked like nothing was getting added to the list.
Thanks for the help anyway :3

Comment: Why not just always add achievements to the queue, even if it is only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for `this`, which refers to the current object that an instance method is called on.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `exampleAchievement` instance?

```
queueList.Add(this);// is this you're looking for?
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If the `ExampleAchievement` is getting this method from its base class `Achievement`, then just do this:

```
queueList.Add(this);
```

and an instance of `ExampleAchievement` will be added to the queue. However, when using it, you'll need to check the type somehow *if there are special properties that aren't visible in the base contract* that you need to get at.

If all properties are simply override properties in the child class, then you won't need to worry about that because you'll get back the child implementation when accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to pass a parameter through that can identify itself as what is calling it?

So

```
public void GetAchievement(string caller)
{

if(caller == "Something")
{
//Do Something
}
else
{
//Do Something else
}
     //If the player hasn't got the achievement yet and another achievement is NOT being drawn, get the achievement
    if (!got && !drawing)
        get = true;
    //If the player hasn't got the achievement yet and another achievement IS being drawn, add the achievement to the queue list
    else if (!got && drawing)
        queueList.Add(); //What do I do here?
}
```

and then call it using  exampleAchievement.GetAchievement(this.name);